# change font size in php

Tags: php, wordpress

trying to change only font size for the 'email' be called in this code. Trying to inject ‘font-size: 15px;’. Trying to do it here so that only the email being called will be a different font size than the default

paragraph text.

```
    <p><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i><?php echo sh_set($meta1, 'email');?> </p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add span tag and insert style for span:

```
<p><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i><span style='font-size:15px'><?php echo sh_set($meta1, 'email');?></span></p>
```

Comment: Hi Ly, Worked perfectly! Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

```
<p style="font-size:15px !important"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i><?php echo sh_set($meta1, 'email');?> </p>
```

Or for php content

```
<p><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i><span style="font-size:15px !important><?php echo sh_set($meta1, 'email');?></span> </p>
```

Comment: Please try my answer, if working then upvote my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "span" tag and apply separate style for it

```
 <p><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i><span class="font-size:15px"><?php echo sh_set($meta1, 'email');?></span> </p>
```

if you dont want to use inline css then use below by applying class name,

```
 <p><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i><span class="email-class"><?php echo sh_set($meta1, 'email');?> </span></p>
```

and in styles use below

```
.email-class{font-size:15px;}
```